# Javascript - Combining multi-dimensional array with index

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, lodash

**I have an multidimensional array which looks like this:**

```
[  
  ["1","2","3","4"],
  ["1","2","3","4"],
  ["1","2","3","4"], 
  ["1","2","3","4"]  
]
```

What I am hoping to accomplish is combining everything into a single array by adding the values of the array by its index.

**Expected result:**

```
[4,8,12,16] //(adding the 4 array values with appropriate index)
```

I see Lodash has a method `_.zip`, but that does not accept array of arrays as input to give the correct value. Is there an easy to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `_.zip` does not accept array of arrays as input,  there is a technical to achieve it.  `_.zip.apply(null, array)`.

It could be done like below. 
*(Note your bottom level elements are strings, so there is one more step to convert them to number.)*

```
var data =[  
  ["1","2","3","4"],
  ["1","2","3","4"],
  ["1","2","3","4"], 
  ["1","2","3","4"]  
];

var result = _.map(_.zip.apply(null, data), function (n) {
  return _.sum(_.map(n, function(x) { return +x; }));
}); 

console.log(result);
```

[**The demo.**](https://jsfiddle.net/3uhxbva6/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm interpreting your question as follows: map each element in the array to it's length plus the value of the previous element. Here is one way you could do that.

```
x = [  
  ["1","2","3","4"],
  ["1","2","3","4"],
  ["1","2","3","4"], 
  ["1","2","3","4"]  
]  
result = x.map(function(a) {
    return a.length;
}
for (i = 1; i < result.length; ++i) {
    result[i] += result[i - 1];
}
```